# Accepting money from non-muslims for charity

Tags: halal-haram, riba, money, sadaqah

I have a doubt with getting money from non-muslims.
Me and my friends just started a group ( a charity group to help and feed poor people in our area).
Some of my non-muslim friends also have much interest to join and help in this group donating money.

So, Is it permissible and lawful in islam to get money from non-muslims for using charity purpose?
Some of my friends doubted that it should not be used because of there are chances of interest and the money may be not in halal way, 
and it is not allowed to use money that is not a part of zakath

Please help in this case, Should I start the charity group?
Im newbie here and thanks in advance for any suggestion and ideas.

Comment: The question is, why not? AFAIK, this was never mentioned as haram. However, you should be careful. There're good people, but there are people with bad intentions too. But, in case *riba'* is involved, the answer is a definite no. Even between muslims and family *riba'* is forbidden :)

Comment: You said, "why not" and "definite no", So what would be the conclusion? as I would not be knowing how the members in the group are making money in halal way or not. And I need to know what the Islamic teaching behind this type of actions.

Comment: Exactly. By default, islam allows everything except those prohibited. Receiving charity was not prohibited, but anything involving riba is. You get my point, bro? :D

Comment: Note that zakat and charity are two different things.

Comment: Yes @BurhanKhalid, Zakah; is the Obligatory Charity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Charity works in Islam are not just bound for Muslim Ummah, Charity is for humanity, by the humanity.

You can surely accept the money from non-muslims if they're willing to help you in your good work. And then inturn you must help non-muslims too, since Islam has no limitations for helping only your Muslims fellows.

Charity is generally meant: ([WikiPedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charity_%28practice%29))

> The practice of **charity** means the voluntary giving of help to those in need. Charity is humanitarian act of temporal principle.

This means, that a person who wants to help others who are in the hour of need. It doesn't have any definition where it has been mentioned that the help must be from Muslims and for the Muslims only. It is a general term.

So you can get the money from non-muslims. But, the only thing to be noted here must be the income source. It must be halaal and should not be earned from bad or evil means.

Also, the money given for Charity has no interest on it. It is not a loan. It is a help-giving-away by person. It is not taken under an oath to be returned after certain period. So, you don't need to worry about the interest on the money.

Charity is to-help, not to-start-business. In this way, you can get the money from all of  those who are **willing** to help others without any sort of consent of getting repaid back with a percentage of profit.

Comment: Thanks. Hope you meant , " It must be halaal and should ""not"" be earned from bad or evil means."" :)

Comment: hehehe yeah I missed that :not: from the answer! hehehe..thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

I think you can accept it. Remember when prophet and followers reached madeena, there were non-muslims who helped them with money,food,shelter,etc. They never asked about halal or something.
 In your case, you can't decide whether it is halal or not even from muslims. Leave it to God and continue your work. All the best for your group.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, If you have valid sources or any comments from scholars, that would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it about the **intention** *YOU* are doing something like that? **If you have doubts about haram money, than you should not do that**, obviously, but if you have no doubts, than there is no problem, because your and their intentions are good.